# Why does loading of an external "async defer" javascript code happen before page load?

Tags: html, javascript, performance, load-time

Recaptcha recommends loading of its script like this:

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
```

I added this to the head section of the html document and checked with Chrome when it is loaded. Chrome says it is loaded before page load (the network tab of chrome devtools indicates the end of the page load with a vertical red line and the above script is loaded before that.

Why is that? Shouldn't adding async defer as recommended by google defer loading of the script after page load?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The page is only fully loaded when *all* linked resources (including `<script async defer`) have loaded. This is when the `onload` event fires.

However, the `DOMContentLoaded` event is likely to fire *before* this - which will probably be *before* the `async defer` scripts have loaded. (I say "probably" - if the browser is able to determine that it can load the script in another thread *at the same time* without slowing things down then I guess it probably will; but with no guarantee.)

Comment: My problem is I'd like to reduce the page load time. Google recommends scripts should be load asynchronously, that's why it says to use the async defer tags. But it's useless if it happens before page load, because then it is added to the page load time, which is what google measures too.

Comment: `async defer` potentially reduces the _perceived_ page load time for the user. It reduces the time to when the document is _ready_. So results in a better user experience. I wouldn't be surprised if Google somehow incorporates these factors into its algorithm. We don't know for sure exactly how/what Googlebot calculates when determining page load time.

Comment: If you want to take this script completely out of the page load time (ie. _after_ the page load event). Then only load/generate the `<script>` element _after_ the page has loaded. However, Googlebot is "probably" capable of running this as well - so will still be able to determine that you are loading more resources (but whether Googlebot sees that as part of the overall load time is another matter).

Comment: _"We don't know for sure exactly how/what Googlebot calculates when determining page load time"_  I wonder why that is. If google wants faster pages from us then it should tell us exactly what it considers page load time, shouldn't it?

Comment: @Tom Not necessarily. We can figure out how to load pages faster, but I don't think Google wants us to figure out how _it_ determines what loads pages faster. Then people will just focus on and game those factors for ranking purposes.

Comment: G suggests a lot of things to reduce the overall/perceived load time of the page, and using `async defer` is certainly one of them. So the "page load time" you see in the browser's network tools is probably not the precise _figure_ that Gbot uses as a ranking factor. G is trying to rank according to _user experience_, which is related to the _perceived_ load time, not necessarily the _actual_ load time. G repeatedly suggests, "Eliminate render-blocking JS and CSS in above-the-fold content" (which `async defer` helps to do) - but this is not going to be measurable in a "simple" page timer.

Comment: @w3dk  _"which is related to the perceived load time, not necessarily the actual load time"_ The problem is, perceived load time is subjective. For example,what happens if at the end of the page I add a 5 second timeout after which facebook like buttons are loaded? (They are not necessary for the page, so it's enough if I load them after 5 seconds.) Will google leave them out of page load time, because they are loaded after 5 seconds? Or will it add them, because they modify the page (content can jump around a bit when the like buttons appear), so they add to the "perceived load time"?